# How do I pass the product ID and attribute to Gallery.php block?

Tags: product-attribute, custom, custom-attributes, gallery, product-id

How do I get product ID and product attribute at
magento/module-catalog/block/product/view/gallery.php?

Please help, I need to do some image filtering by product custom attribute with the image caption.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getProduct()` function directly in this file because that extends below file which contain this function.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/AbstractView.php

You can use below line to get Product ID in that file..

```
<?php $productId = $this->getProduct()->getId(); ?>
```

And you can get attribute value using this line

```
<?php $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); ?>
```

You can replace your attribute code with `attribute_code`.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks! you are life saver!

Comment: Can you please upvote? Thanks 

Comment: Is there any other way to get the product custom attribute code? I don't know why it doesn't work on my other page <?php $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); ?>  or I have to include something? please help

Comment: Where you're using this code ? **<?php $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); ?>** can you please let me know so I can check.

Comment: I was adding some custom php script inside, I need to get the product custom attribute called "image_type", app/code/vendor/Tools/Block/Product/Bundle/Configurable.php  Thanks! I am very apperciate your help.

Comment: Can you please try this once ? **<?php $this->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('image_type')->getFrontend()->getValue($this->getProduct()); ?>**

Comment: oh ...sorry....<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on boolean in /var/www/app/code......etc

Comment: If you use **$this->getProduct()->getId()** then you get product ID there ?

Comment: Yes you right, I can get product id

Comment: I am sorry, I think I am wrong, the product ID I got, is the configurable product ID, not the main bundle ID. Is there anyway to get the Bundle ID at this location? app/code/vendor/Tools/Block/Product/Bundle/Configurable.php

Comment: Sorry @PaulFan, But I don't know here which class you've extended there. Can you please let me know that ?

Comment: namespace myself\Tools\Block\Product\Bundle;

use Ewave\ExtendedBundleProduct\Block\Product\Bundle\Configurable as EwaveConfigurable;

class Configurable extends EwaveConfigurable ,

 The change I made is base on this (Ewave extension)->(extend),
so, there is a extend custom place 
 file at app\code\myself\Tools\Block\Product\Bundle\Configurable.php which is overwrite one of the function inside app\code\Ewave\ExtendedBundleProduct\Block\Product\Bundle\Configurable.php